# Will subtitling my Youtube videos make them easier to find in search engines?

Tags: seo, youtube

Youtube has a function for subtitling uploaded videos. If I do that, will they be easier to find in search engines? Does search engines index the subtitles on Youtube?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a website you control. This is a usage question for another site. Questions asked here should be about managing a site you own or control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, YouTube has been able to index the closed captioning for a little over a year - which helps in a big way for optimization.

More info [here](https://www.shoutmeloud.com/youtube-seo-tips.html).